# Différence entre « en haut / en bas » et « au-dessus / au-dessous »

Tags: adverbes, indications-de-lieu

Quelle est la différence entre « en haut / en bas » et « au-dessus / au-dessous » ?

Sont-ils  synonymes tout le temps ou y a-t-il des situations où l'utilisation de l'un ou de l'autre est préférable ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Avec un complément, *au dessus de l'objet* signifie plus haut que cet objet, tandis que *en haut de l'objet* pointe vers la partie haute de l'objet, mais pas plus haut. Le trait d'union dans *au-dessus* est optionnel. La situation est symétrique pour *au dessous de l'objet* et *en bas de l'objet*. On peut dire *au(-)dessous* ou *en(-)dessous*, il n'y a pas (plus ?) vraiment de différence ; *en-dessus* est beaucoup plus rare.

Il y a également *sur l'objet* qui signifie plus haut que l'objet mais en restant en contact, tandis que au-dessus implique qu'il n'y a pas de contact. La distinction entre *au-dessous* et *sous* est moins tranchée.

Pour compliquer les choses, *dessus* et *dessous* sont également des noms qui désignent la face supérieure et inférieure respectivement. Ceci peut rendre *au dessus* ambigu (et pareil avec *dessous*) : il peut s'agir du dessus de quelque chose dans un complément introduit par *à*, ou de la locution *au-dessus* (le trait d'union élimine l'ambiguïté). En pratique le contexte rend en générale la phrase claire ; de temps en temps il faut dire quelque chose comme « sur le dessus » ou « plus haut que » pour désambiguer.

*Au dessus/dessous* est toujours relatif, mais l'objet peut être implicite. Par contre *en haut/bas* peut être utilisé de manière absolue : « regarde en haut » peut signifier « regarde le haut de l'objet dont nous parlons » ou « lève les yeux plus haut que l'horizontale ».

---

> L'oiseau vole au-dessus du toit. *The bird flies above the roof.*
> Le ballon est sur le toit. *The ball lies on the roof.*
> Le dessus du toit est peint en rouge. *The top side of the roof is painted red.*
> Le haut du toit s'appelle le faîte. *The top part of the roof is called the pinnacle.*
>
> Le livre est sur l'étagère du bas de la bibliothèque. *The book is on the bottom shelf of the bookcase.*
> La bille a roulé sous [ou *au dessous de*] la bibliothèque. *The marble rolled under/underneath the bookcase.*

← au dessus de l'objet

← sur l'objet
|——————————|    ← le dessus de l'objet
|          |    ← en haut de l'objet
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |    ← en bas de l'objet
|——————————|    ← le dessous de l'objet
              ← sous l'objet

← au dessous de l'objet

---

With a complement, *au dessus de l'objet* means above this object, whereas *en haut de l'objet* means level with the upper part of the object. The hyphen in *au-dessus* is optional (it may be considered mandatory by some prescriptive sources, but I don't think this holds in practice). *Au dessous* and *en bas* are symmetric. *En(-)dessous* is a synonym of *au-dessous*; *en-dessus* exists but is a lot rarer.

An important addition to this list *sur l'objet* (on the objet) and *sous l'objet* (under the object). *Sur* is above and in contact, while *au-dessus* implies that there is no contact, like *on* vs *above* in English. The distinction between *sous* and *au-dessous* is less marked.

Just to make things more complex, *dessus* and *dessous* are also nouns which designate the upper and lower surface of an object. An expression like *au dessus* (and likewise with *dessous*) could be ambiguous: it could designate the *dessus* part of the object in a complement introduced by the preposition *à*, or it could mean above the object. In practice this is usually clear from context. If not, expressions such as *sur le dessus* (on the top surface of …) or *plus haut que* (higher than …) can clarify the matter.

Comment: Très bonne réponse, j'aime l'art ASCII :) Fin, ce n'est pas vraiment de l'art quoi, mais je l'aime tout de même!

Comment: Je ne sais pas s'il s'agit d'une différence régionale,  mais il me semble que les deux sont interchangeables, au Québec.

Answer (score 9):

Regarder *en haut* : diriger son regard *au-dessus* de l'horizon, ou lever le regard *au-dessus* de sa position actuelle ; pour *en bas* ce sera *en dessous*.

*En haut* désigne la zone la plus élevée d'un objet ou d'un espace ; en bas la moins élevée.

On emploie souvent *en haut* (ou *en bas*) pour signifier l'endroit où l'action va se porter, ou pour signifier une position symbolique :

> - « En bas de l'échelle sociale », il n'y a pas d'*en dessous*, de situation plus basse possible, sinon on est hors de la société.
> - « Tout *en haut* de cette rue il la place des fêtes ; on monte en haut de la colline pour admirer le panorama » alors que l'on ne peut monter *au-dessus* de cette rue ou de la colline, seuls les oiseaux, les avions, les nuages... sont *au-dessus*.

*Au-dessus (de)* ou *en dessous* (de) s'emploie par rapport à un objet précis ou une position donnée :

> - "Il n'y a rien *au-dessus* de l'amour  affirment certains romantiques" : il n’y a pas d'*en haut* par rapport à quelque chose, à un sentiment, une idée... (mais il y a un *en haut* possible pour la chose, le sentiment, l'idée…)
> - « Ce type est *au-dessous* de tout » : on ne peut rien attendre de cette personne, on ne peut rien lui confier, son comportement est inadmissible.
> - Il y a des oiseaux qui volent *au-dessus* de la surface de la mer et des poissons qui nagent *en dessous*

Des significations différentes :

> - « Les voisins *en dessous* sont-ils sympathiques ? » indique généralement les voisins mitoyens *en dessous* de votre appartement.
> - « Les voisins *en bas* sont très bruyants » pour signifier le bruit que font les voisins du rez-de-chaussée qui peuvent être *en dessous* de (à la verticale de) votre appartement (qui est *au-dessus* du deuxième étage, ou *plus haut* dans les étages) ou sur tout le niveau du  rez-de-chaussée ; on entend le bruit en dessous de la ligne d'horizon.

Comment: Bizarrement le correcteur orthographique supprime le `-` de *en dessous* et le laisse pour *au-dessus*

Answer (score 9):

On peut considérer « en haut / en bas »  comme des indicateurs de position ***absolus***, ces indicateurs se *suffisant à eux-mêmes* pour donner une position pleinement compréhensible. Il n'y a généralement pas plusieurs façons d'être « en haut / en bas ».

En revanche, « au-dessus / au-dessous » sont des indicateurs ***relatifs***, du fait que bien souvent, ils *ne se suffisent pas à eux-mêmes* pour indiquer clairement la position. Un objet est « au-dessus / au-dessous » par rapport à un autre objet.